# Android: how to scroll page by page like Feedly instead of usual smooth scrolling

Tags: android, user-interface

Recently, I have tried Feedly for reading news. I wonder how can we implement the page by page scrolling in Android instead of default smooth scrolling.

Comment: hey, I also want to develop page like that. But, Feedly's code is not native. So, I m trying with VerticalViewPager by myself. For item count, I calculate base on Screen height and item height. Hope you can find a way. :)